# Why did my teacher integrate \varphi in the opposite direction while solving a triple integral for volume in spherical coordinates?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

In Calculus III class today we learned how to evaluate triple integrals in spherical coordinates.
One of the example questions we worked on was to use a triple integral to find the volume of a shape.

Use spherical coordinates to find the volume of the region $Q$ bounded by the cylinders $r = 1$ and $r = 2$, and the cones $\varphi = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\varphi = \frac{\pi}{6}$.

The image provided by the book is.

[image: Image of the problem described]

While working ahead I found $dV = \rho^2 \sin\varphi d\rho d\varphi d\theta$, $\rho_1 = \csc\varphi$, and $\rho_2 = 2\csc\varphi$ and used this information to evaluate the integral:

$$\iiint_QdV = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_{\csc\varphi}^{2\csc\varphi} \rho^2 \sin\varphi d\rho d\varphi d\theta = \frac{28\pi}{3\sqrt3}$$

The teacher finally caught up and agreed on everything I wrote, but she wrote the middle integral as $\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}$.
This makes no sense to me because $\frac{\pi}{6} < \frac{\pi}{3}$ and when increasing the value of $\varphi$ $\frac{\pi}{6}$ is encountered first followed later by $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Her argument for doing it this way is that $\frac{\pi}{3}$ is encountered first when traveling from the xy-plane in the positive z direction, which was what we considered when finding the limits of integration in rectangular coordinates.
Doing it her way the answer is $-\frac{28\pi}{3\sqrt3}$ which is negative, and therefore doesn't represent volume.
I don't think that her way is correct. Especially since it directly contradicts the questions we worked over before this one.

**Which way is the right way?** I want to be sure I understand this correctly.

Comment: I would say - in spherical coordinates, the angle can be specified differently, e.g. $\in \langle 0, \pi\rangle$ or $\in \langle -\pi/2,\pi/2\rangle$. This can lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: The system we use in class is $\{ (\rho,\varphi,\theta) | 0 \leq \rho, 0 \leq \varphi \leq \pi, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi\}$. Where $\varphi = 0$ is the positive z-axis. This is shown in the image I provided showing the two cones. EDIT: Used wrong inequality at first.

Comment: So I would say, Your procedure is correct.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was thinking. Thank you very much!